# Connecting two devices using GKPeerPickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gksession

I have three devices(mac, ipod, iphone) all of them are connected to the wi-fi. When I am testing application, that connects two devices, both ask to switch on the bluetooth, but anyway, they want to use wi-fi. how to force them to use bluetooth instead of wi-fi.

```
GKPeerPickerController*     picker;
picker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc]init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby; //Here, I suppose, program should use BlueTooth(but it uses the same network).
[picker show];
```

But if one device is not connected to the wi-fi, everything works fine.
Why setting connectionTypesMask to GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby uses first of all Internet connection and only then uses Bluetooth connection? How to force use only Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to do that: turn off airport in MacBook and turn on the BT.

Answer (score 0):

This code for  GKPeerPickerController delegate method is from Mark and LaMarche Beginning iOS 5 development:

```
-(GKSession*)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker sessionForConnectionType:(GKPeerPickerConnectionType)type
{
GKSession *theSession;
if (type == GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby)
{
    theSession = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:kTicTacToeSessionID displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];
}
return theSession;
}
```

It will ensure you only connect BT sessions. In their example project some hidden functionality of the peerPicker makes the device ask you to turn on BlueTooth.